# Are there any well performing methods for representing a NA in a array?

Tags: c++, nan, boost-variant

*Note I'm specifically referring to the term NA and not NaN because I'm not including only number types*

I've been attempting to represent NA values within arrays of different types such as:

`int`, `float`, `bool`, `string`, `class`

However I've been having trouble coming up with good methods to represent NA values which don't significantly hurt performance.

For example using a `boost::variant` named `StringNA` with the type `string` and a struct representing a NA `struct NA`, and then creating an array of type `StringNA`, is one way of representing a NA value in a array.

But this caused significant performance issues as first I have to check what type the `StringNA` is holding and second `boost::get` cast it to get the string.

This is just one idea that I've had. Is there any better methods out there for achieving this?

Just as visualize the problem here is what I'm hoping to achieve:

`["String", NA, "String2", "String3", NA]`

The amount of NAs in an array are unknown at compile time

Comment: [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)?

Comment: fwiw, you cannot avoid to first check if the value is available before you access it. In one way or the other you will have to pay for it

Comment: What about using `variant` visitation? This is often done as a jump-map where the visitor overloads are stored in an array, and the index of the active alternative is used to perform the visitation. I can't say whether boost implements it this way, but the C++ standard requires it (at least for single-variant visitation it must be constant time -- which forces this)

Comment: Use two arrays of identical size: One stores the actual data, the other one stores a flag whether the item is NA. I believe this improve the memory layout and thus performance. As always: measure.

Comment: `class` is not a type.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann This is a interesting solution that I also considered. Are there any examples of this implementation you can link?

Comment: If the NA's outnumber the others you could use some kind of sparse array.